# Prove that $e^x$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $f(x)=e^x$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

I tried to show that all $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ function that has no bounded derivative is not uniformly continuous.

Suppose by contradiction it is. There there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon $ when $|x-y|<\delta $. Then, how to continue ?

Comment: I'm not so sure that $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ function that has not bounded derivate are necessarily uniformly continuous, but I can't provide a counter example right now. On $(0,1)$ it wouldn't be true as $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous but has no bounded derivated. So I guess a $\frac{1}{2}-$Holder function over $\mathbb R$ s.t. is not $\alpha -$holder for all $\alpha >\frac{1}{2}$ should be a counter example.

Comment: For a counter-example, think of a function that has shorter and shorter spikes around each positive integer, with steeper and steeper sides. You can choose the height and steepness of each spike so that the function is uniformly continuous with unbounded derivative.

Answer (score 3):

For exponential in particular (i.e. avoiding the regularity), suppose it's uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$. Then there is $\delta >0$ s.t. for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and all $|h|\leq \delta $, $$|e^{x+h}-e^x|\leq 1.$$
Therefore, for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and all $|h|\leq \delta $, $$|e^{h}-1|\leq e^{-x}\underset{x\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$
And thus for all $0<|h|\leq \delta $, you get $e^h=1$, which is of course a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x>y$, $r:=x-y >0$, and

$\epsilon >0$;

Assume there is a $\delta >0$ s.t.

$0<r<\delta$ implies

$|e^x-e^y|=|e^y(e^r-1)|=$

$e^y|e^r-1| <\epsilon$.

Choose $x-y=r=\delta/2$.

Then

$|e^x-e^y|=e^y(e^{\delta/2}-1)$;

Note : $e^{\delta/2}-1:=u >0$.

For $y$ large enough:

$u e^y >\epsilon$.

Contradiction.